# Created an instance with ubuntu-emulator, but cannot run it (stuck at busybox, black screen, does nothing)

Tags: boot, ubuntu-touch, 16.10, ubuntu-emulator

I created an emulator on Ubuntu 16.10 the following way:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-emulator
sudo ubuntu-emulator create TouchEmulator
```

but when I try to run it:

```
sudo ubuntu-emulator run TouchEmulator --memory 1024 --scale 0.7
```

a completely black screen appears (I can only see the 'case' of the phone it imitates).
In the terminal the following is shown:

```
/scripts/panic/adbd: line 22: can't create/sys/class/android_usb/android0/idVendor: nonexistent directory
/scripts/panic/adbd: line 23: can't create /sys/class/android_usb/android0/idProduct: nonexistent directory
/scripts/panic/adbd: line 24: can't create /sys/class/android_usb/android0/functions: nonexistent directory
/scripts/panic/adbd: line 25: can't create /sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable: nonexistent directory
[    0.803272] initrd: starting adbd for USB debugging
/sbin/adbd: error while loading shared libraries: libgio-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-9ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

(I've tried the i386 version, running with more/less memory, not scaling.)
I have OpenGL support.